# How to optimize query that has the same subquery twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to improve some queries performance, the queries' structure is something as follows:

```
select 'Total_amount', 
(select SUM(Total) from dbo.Invoices i where i.BU = bun.BU), 
case when (select SUM(Total) from dbo.Invoices i where i.BU = bun.BU) > 100000 then 'Good' else 'Not good' end 
from dbo.BusinessUnits bun
```

I know this example can be solved using joins, but on my real queries I need the subqueries. 
As you may notice, I have the same subquery twice, one to give the actual value and another one to calculate a status.

Is there a way to improve performance by just calculating the subquery once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try using **OUTER APPLY** like this:-

```
select 'Total_amount', SumTotal, case when SumTotal > 100000 
then 'Good' else 'Not good' end 
from dbo.BusinessUnits bun 
OUTER APPLY (select SUM(Total) 
from dbo.Invoices i where i.BU = bun.BU) CA(SumTotal)
```

SPECIAL THANKS TO **[MARTIN SMITH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith)** for pointing that!!

Comment: I'm trying to use the first approach but I get an error telling the name of the column is not valid

Comment: Thanks! This improved the total execution time in about 40%!. I also tried using the with option, but it performs better using variables

Comment: @sqlint:- Yes I agree.But the idea was to tell OP to use variables so as to increase the performance(which certainly has increase to 40%)

Comment: This isn't the same thing. In the OP's original query it is a correlated sub query. You can't assign it to a scalar variable. You are summing all `Total` not just those for a particular `BU`

Comment: Maybe they didn't check the results very carefully.

Comment: You could try defining it in an `OUTER APPLY`. Not guaranteed but often works.

Comment: `select 'Total_amount', SumTotal, case when SumTotal > 100000 then 'Good' else 'Not good' end from dbo.BusinessUnits bun OUTER APPLY (select SUM(Total) from dbo.Invoices i where i.BU = bun.BU) CA(SumTotal)`

Comment: @MartinSmith:- Thanks a lot Sir!! Updated my answer!! Didnt remove the original one as OP may find the difference in future!!!

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the syntax - what's `CA` here, an arbitrary name?

Answer (score 1):

[Another option using WITH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
WITH total_table( 'Total_amount' )
AS
( SELECT SUM(Total) 
  FROM Invoices INNER JOIN  BusinessUnits ON (Invoices.BU = BusinessUnits.BU )
)

SELECT
   CASE WHEN Total_amount > 100000 then 'Good'
   ELSE 'Not good' 
   END
FROM
   total_table
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax. The `where i.BU = bun.BU` cannot be used inside the CTE definition.

Comment: Now it will return different results. A single row. Not a row per `BusinessUnits` row.